# Clear from workspace base

Tags: matlab

I've toto.m + model.mdl
from a function toto.m , I open model which load variable in workspace
after closing model I want to clear variables loaded in workspace 
is there a way to do that without using clear all?

```
function toto

model = 'model1';
open_system(model1);
close_system(model1);
end
```

when I run the function the workspace isn't cleared , how could I clear variable only used by model without using clear all ?

Comment: `clear` will do. Seriously, you should first tell us what your problem with `clear all` is.

Comment: There is also [`clearvars`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html), it has a nifty `-except` flag that `clear` does not have. But no idea if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clear` followed by a list of variables, for example `clear a b c`. However, I don't know whether there is a method that clears all the variables declared in a given script, though you can always use functions so all the variables in the scope of the function will be cleared when it ends.

Comment: I usually use prefixes that add some sense to the name of the variables. If you do also do this, you can use the wildcard '\*' in order to delete all the variables that begin with that prefix. For example, 'tmp_a=1; tmp_b=2;clear tmp*'

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clear all variables except those that existed already before running the script, you can temporarily store these already existing variable names and run clear afterwards using:

```
already_existing_vars = who;

% your actual script ...
% ...

% clear variables created in this script
vars_to_clear = setdiff(who,already_existing_vars);
clear(vars_to_clear{:},'vars_to_clear')
```

Comment: hello, if I want only to clear all variables at the end how could I do that without doinf clear a,b,c,....etc ?

Comment: @lola If you meant to clear all variables, just use `clear`. There's nothing wrong using it imo.